# scanf("%d/%d%c%d/%d", &num1, &denom1, &sign, &num2, &denom2); Keeps on scanning for user input at the console

Tags: c, scanf

`scanf("%d/%d%c%d/%d", &num1, &denom1, &sign, &num2, &denom2);` keeps on scanning for user input at the console, no matter how many integers or characters I enter. The program does not proceed further. What is happening here?

By the way my code is as follows

```
#include<stdio.h>
//------------------------START OF MAIN()--------------------------------------
int main(void)
{
    printf("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
    
    int num1, denom1, num2, denom2, result_num, result_denom,flag=1;
    char sign;

    printf("Enter fraction1 operator fraction2(operators + - * /): ");
    scanf("%d/%d%c%d/%d", &num1, &denom1, &sign, &num2, &denom2);  //doesn't work. Won't stop taking inputs
         //three scanfs --for fraction1, operator, fraction2--also takes unlimited inputs.
         //A scanf to read fraction1, getchar to read operator and another scanf to read fraction2 works fine.
    //scanf("%d/%d", &num1, &denom1);
    //sign=getchar();
    //scanf("%d/%d",&num2, &denom2);
    
    switch(sign)
    {
        case '+':
            result_num = num1 * denom2 + num2 * denom1;
            result_denom = denom1 * denom2;
            break;
        case '-':
            result_num = num1 * denom2 - num2 * denom1;
            result_denom = denom1 * denom2;
            break;
        case '*':
            result_num = num1 * num2;
            result_denom = denom1 * denom2;
            break;
        case '/':
            result_num = num1 * denom2;
            result_denom = denom1 * num2;
            break;
        default:
            flag=0;
            printf("Invalid Operator.");
    }
    if(flag)
        printf("The result is %d/%d", result_num, result_denom);
    
    printf("\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
    return 0;
}
//-------------------------END OF MAIN()---------------------------------------
```

The input I tried to enter is `31/8+7/4`. And I press enter, but the program won't proceed further.
If I use the following three statements viz, `scanf()`, `getchar()`, `printf()` instead (which are commented), I am able to execute the program without issues (as long as there is no line feed while entering the input). What is happening here?

Comment: Good news is: your code works fine on my machine. Bad news is: your code works fine on my machine, and not yours. The issue doesn't seem to stem from what you've written.

Comment: @OctaveL The compiler i am using is clang, and i tried this code on both both c99 and c11 standards. Do you think this in anyway the reason i am facing that issue?

Comment: I would have said your environment or even OS would be the most likely culprit, although it sounds to me like it's most likely something a lot more basic we're overlooking. FYI, I'm on Linux and I can run it fine with clang as well (for both C99 and C11)

Comment: Works here too. MSVC not strictly conformant but I don't see why the input should be refused.  Can you please post the exact input in `code format` ? Note if you use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` and *check the return value* (which should be 5 here) it is much easier to discard bad input and repeat.

Comment: @Weather Vane, the input i tried `31/8+7/4`. I am still a very much beginner, following a book. i didn't face `fgets()` or `sscanf()` yet.

Comment: @OctaveL, seems you are right. The same code works fine in online compilers.

Comment: You *must* always check the value returned by `scanf()` which is the number of items successfully converted. That will tell you which part is being refused. For example if `scanf()` returns `1` then it was refusing at the second format specifier.

Comment: Try changing the format specifier to `%d/%d %c %d/%d`

Comment: I thank you both for responding.

Comment: @Loki, Yes i tried that. I even tried `%d%d%c%d%d`. And also tried ```scanf(%d%d);   scanf(%c);   scanf(%d%d);``` individual statements.